# Chebotarev Density Theorem

Tags: number-theory

I wish to read the Chebotarev Density Theorem over number fields. I am familiar with the Decomposition group, Inertia group, Artin Symbol etc. Someone please provide me some article which contains the detailed proof of the theorem over number fields and which is easy to go through.

Comment: Lagarias, J.C.; Odlyzko, A.M. (1977). "Effective Versions of the Chebotarev Theorem". Algebraic Number Fields: 409–464

Comment: http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118390180.html

Comment: http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/chebotarev.pdf